# Is it possible to get contract messages from Geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, message

When I use the etherchain.org API to get all the transactions in a block, it also returns contract messages.  For example for block 911516, this call returns 7 transactions:

https://etherchain.org/api/block/911516/tx

However when I use this query in Geth for the same block, it reports only one transaction:

```
web3.eth.getBlockTransactionCount(911516)
```

Apparently etherchain.org includes contract-to-contract messages in addition to transactions.  Is there a way to obtain these messages in Geth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in general. Internal calls to other contracts are only part of single transaction execution.

However, if a called contract emits logs they are available in transaction receipts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to look it at [Ether.camp project](https://live.ether.camp/block/911516), i looked at it contracts, raw info.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible currently with both Geth and Parity, although with non-standard APIs. See the answers to [How to get contract internal transactions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3417/how-to-get-contract-internal-transactions).