# What is the composition of the blockchain database?

Tags: blockchain, storage, memory, database, leveldb

From [axic's explanation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2194/271) of the structure of the ethereum database, we learned that data is stored in [Merkle Patricia tries](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Patricia-Tree), usually inside a [LevelDB store](http://leveldb.org/). It consists of structures such as `blocks`, `transactions`, `accounts` and `storage`.

How large are these various components of the blockchain database?

And in general, what are the findings of data analysis of the blockchain?

Comment: Note that the questions you're asking relate to a particular _implementation_ of Ethereum. There's nothing intrinsic in the protocol that requires this particular arrangement of storage. You should edit your question to specify what implementation(s) your question is about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `account` is a local object to easily track changes on the accounts (with a StateObject db). The size depends on the nbr of transactions you execute with this account. An unused account should be less than 1kB.
- The maximum theoretical size for a `contract` is [beyond technology limits](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1038/is-there-a-theoretical-limit-for-amount-of-data-that-a-contract-can-store), and actually [*around 90kB*](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/is-there-a-limit-for-transaction-size).
- The `block`.Body contains `Transactions`. The minimum size of a transaction is less than 100 bytes. And **there are no limits for transaction and block size.** [The practical limit is on the gas spent to execute the transaction](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/is-there-a-limit-for-transaction-size).
- (May 2016): it takes **[less than 2GB](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/143/what-are-the-ethereum-disk-space-needs) to synchronize the entire blockchain**