# chaindata data structure

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

What are the schema and data stored in geth's chaindata directory?
There are blockchain data under datadir/chaindata in geth. What is kind of data is stored in LevelDB? What are the actual key and value in the database?

Comment: I couldn't find any information about the schema and actual data stored in LevelDB. What is the actual key and value in LevelDB?

Comment: More information: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2184/exploring-and-analyzing-the-ethereum-blockchain/2194#2194