# How can I parse local Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, blockchain, ether

I need to parse live Ethereum blockchain to retrieve all transactions that belongs to particular smart contract's address.

So my general question is how can I do it properly?

My thought about it so far:

- Need to download blockchain on my local machine
- Loop thought all blockchain block-by-block and filter transactions against smart contract address that I'm interested in.
- Store retrieved information in JSON file.

As far I know, Ethereum blockchain format is LevelDb and I guess it's doable.
Could please help me this my task and point to right direction?

Comment: When you say "live" chain, do you mean parsing the DB while it is updated with live blocks/transactions, i.e. by a running Ethereum client? If so, it might be easier to do the same thing through web3 RPC: personally I found it easily corrupts the db with such usage. Although admittedly, web3 is also a pain, as the information can't be retrieved in batch (always single block or transaction)

Comment: Also see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2184/exploring-and-analyzing-the-ethereum-blockchain

Comment: I needed the same and ended up using Etherscan.io's API, it's free and provides [exactly](https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts) what you want, although keep in mind the usage is limited.