# filter for non-contract addresses?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, filters

If I set up a [filter](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_newfilter) to receive changes, I only seem to receive transactions for addresses that are contract addresses.

How to put a filter to receive transactions that are sent to an address that is non-contract?

Comment: that other question is asking about a contract address, I'm not

Comment: Quite right, I misunderstood your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the topic filter API, which filters for events emitted by contracts; naturally, only contracts are going to show up in that.

Instead, you need to define a [block filter](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_newblockfilter) and iterate over each transaction in the returned block, looking for transactions that target the desired account. Note that this won't catch all value transfers - see [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3417/how-to-get-contract-internal-transactions) for why.

Comment: you mention "a contract that sends ether", but I said I'm not interested in contracts, I'm interested in A->B transfers of ether, where B is an account (not a contract address)

Comment: You're right; see my updated answer.

Comment: the transfers that are not going to be caught are the ones that are sent from A to B where A is a contract address instead of an account?

Comment: @knocte Right - any transfer from a contract won't show up.

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_newpendingtransactionfilter also worked, if you include this in your answer I will upvote, thanks

Comment: @knocte Anyone can propose edits! :) Bear in mind that pending transactions may or may not be included in a block.

Comment: sure, I can do that myself, but I always prefer to check with the original author

Comment: Nice answer Nick. I have a related question to filters myself, any chance you could check it out? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/22802/understanding-web3-eth-filter-parameters Simple misunderstanding of how parameters work I think