# Understanding web3.eth.filter parameters

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, filters

I have been looking through that `web3.eth.filter` function, and ran into a bit of a wall:

```
var options = {
  fromBlock: "pending",
  toBlock: "latest",
  address: "0xab1323fe3234234234fa34324324234af3423432",
};
var filter = web3.eth.filter(options);
```

in regards to the "pending" and "latest" strings, this is the definition I got from github:

> latest may be given to mean the most recent and pending currently
>   mining, block

**source:** https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethfilter

**QUESTION:**

What does that actually mean? If I run `geth` for instance and there are a bunch of blocks pending to be added to the blockchain, lets imagine each "-" represents 1 block in the following example:

```
- - - - - - - - -
```

If I had `fromBlock: "pending"` to `toBlock: "latest"`, would that mean the following:

```
(start here) - - - - - - - - - (end here)
```

But if that were the case, there would be more blocks added by the time the end is reached:

```
(start here) - - - - - - - - - (end here) - -
```

So would latest mean **continue forever** or **stop on the one that was the latest when the filter was actually created** ?

Answer (score 1):

The term `latest` "dynamically updates". That's why if you call web3.eth.filter(...).watch() you'll find new logs added. At least, this is what I see using `testrpc`. You may experience delays on the mainnet.