# Access to list of internal transactions via etherscan API

Tags: transactions, explorers, etherscan

Is there any way to get a list of all of the internal transactions which affect an account, as presented on the etherscan "internal transactions" page on etherscan, using their API?

Or any other block explorer API?

Comment: There's a discussion about this exact issue here: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8315/confused-by-internal-transactions

Comment: check this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/44045/etherscan-api-not-showing-internal-transactions

Comment: https://api.etherscan.io/apis