# Etherscan api not showing internal transactions

Tags: etherscan, internal-transactions

For example:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x4e646a576917a6a47d5b0896c3e207693870869d#internaltx

If I make an api call for the same address as:

> http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlistinternal&address=0x4e646a576917a6a47d5b0896c3e207693870869d&startblock=0&endblock=2702578&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

and got the below response:

```
{"status":"0","message":"No transactions found","result":[]}
```

This contains some internal transactions but etherscan api is not showing them. What is the reason?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The endBlock parameter is 2702578, which is before any of the internal transactions happened.

Change it to 9999999 and it will work.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlistinternal&txhash={txHash}&apikey={apiKey}
```

You need to signup and generate an api key. to use testnet. use the following format

```
https://{testnet}.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlistinternal&txhash={txHash}&apikey={apiKey}
```

testnet values can be ropstan, rinkeby, kovan etc.