# EVM internal transactions

Tags: evm, internal-transactions

I under stand that a contract calling another contract will generate an internal transaction that is not recorded in the blockchain. This usually happens after `CALL` opcode.

I'm wondering if there are any other opcodes that can generate internal transactions? and if this is mentioned anywhere in the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/4475/23391), Contract Transactions or Internal Transactions can be generated from the following opcodes:

```
CREATE
CALL
CALLCODE
DELAGATECALL
SUICIDE
```

As well, there's more to it than just tracking the opcodes. See that answer for more details.