# send VS call - differences and when to use and when not to use

Tags: solidity, security, contract-invocation, fallback-function

Can somebody please explain the differences between using a send and call for contracts and when to use and not use these different methods?

For example :

```
   msg.sender.send(number);  
   msg.sender.call.value(number)();
```

I know that send uses 2300 gas and that using call does not use any gas.

Answer (score 15):

EDIT Dec 2019: `call.value()()` should now be used for transferring ether.  (Do not use send or transfer.)

See:
[Is transfer() still safe after the Istanbul update?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78124/is-transfer-still-safe-after-the-istanbul-update-2300-gas-limitation)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was also looking for more information about how these different methods work on the system level. For example, does the call method generate transactions on the blockchain?

Comment: A `.call` does not create a transaction; just wrote this which has other details you may be looking for: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/6477/42

Comment: I think `send` sends more than 0 gas, doesn't it? It sends 23000

Comment: `send` sends 0 gas, but there's an EVM rule that the receiver always gets a stipend of 2,300 gas (so that if it wants, it always has enough gas to log that it received something).

Comment: Alex Darby is probably confusing `.call` from Javascript (no transaction) with `.call` in Solidity (already in a transaction).

Comment: No, I am not confusing the call from the Javascript. My post does not mention Javascript,

Answer (score 6):

[`address.transfer()`](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=transfer#address-related)

- reverts on failure
- forwards `2,300` gas stipend, safe against reentrancy
- should be used in most cases as it's the safest way to send ether

[`address.send()`](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=transfer#address-related)

- returns `false` on failure
- forwards `2,300` gas stipend, safe against reentrancy
- should be used in rare cases when you want to handle failure in the contract

[`address.call.value().gas()()`](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=transfer#address-related)

- returns `false` on failure
- forwards all available gas, allows specifying how much gas to forward
- should be used when you need to control how much gas to forward when sending ether or to call a function of another contract

You can read more details here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/38642/18932

Answer (score 5):

**1** `Send()` does not forward gas anymore. It simply uses the hardcoded stipend (2300 gas) siphoned from the value transfer cost (minimum 9040). It's enough to send ether, but also enough to basically do one additional small logging operation (in a fallback function). The following operations will consume more gas than the stipend provided to a fallback function:

• Writing to storage

• Creating a contract

• Calling an external function which consumes a large amount of gas

• Sending Ether

**2**  If a `send()` call runs out of gas, it does not throw an error, it simply returns false.

from solidity Doc:

> If a contract receives Ether (without a function being called), the
>   fallback function is executed. The contract can only rely on the “gas
>   stipend” (2300 gas) being available to it at that time. This stipend
>   is not enough to access storage in any way. To be sure that your
>   contract can receive Ether in that way, check the gas requirements of
>   the fallback function (for example in the “details” section in
>   browser-solidity).
>
> • There is a way to forward more gas to the  receiving contract using
>   addr.call.value(x)(). This is essentially the same as addr.send(x), only that it forwards all remaining gas and opens up the ability for the recipient to perform more expensive actions.
>    This might include calling back into the sending contract or
>    other state changes you might not have though of. So it allows for
>    great flexibility for honest users but also for malicious actors.

**Warning**: Contracts that receive Ether but do not define a fallback function throw an exception, sending back
the Ether (this was different before Solidity v0.4.0). So if you want your contract to receive Ether, you have to
implement a fallback function.

Comment: Good points.  For clarity to readers, "does not throw an error, it simply returns false" also applies to `.call()`.  And can't emphasize enough that `.call()` "allows for great flexibility for honest users but also for malicious actors."