# Getting internal transactions of Ethereum transactions over RPC

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, json-rpc

I'd like to parse Ethereum transactions, so that I know internal transactions (the contract calling other contracts) and the amount of gas those used. For example the information is available here:

http://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0x87a147aebe94eb532f951d55a10659ca62955bb1ba29f6aecdf1ddf069b96585#internal

I see I can get the transaction receipt object using `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt` RPC method. How one would proceed from here and determine what internal transctions the transaction made?

Comment: Duplicate http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/3417/620