# Including contract-driven transactions in historical transaction script results

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, internal-transactions

The goal is to create a .csv file of all ethereum transactions essentially a large table with these columns

`blocknumber, timestamp, fromaddress, toaddress, value`

I wrote this script to run in the REPL for go-ethereum 1.5.0-unstable, installed from the ubuntu package manager after adding the ethereum and ethereum-dev ppas :

```
function csv(){
    var i,l,block,j,k,trans;
    var s;
    for(i=0,l=web3.eth.blockNumber;i<l;i++){
        block = web3.eth.getBlock(i, true);
        if (block && block.miner)
            console.log([i,block.timestamp,'M',block.miner,5].join(","));
        if (block && block.transactions){
            for(j=0,k=block.transactions.length;j<k;j++){
                trans = block.transactions[j];
                console.log([i,block.timestamp,trans.from,trans.to,
                             +web3.fromWei(trans.value,'ether')].join(","));
            }
        }
    }
};

csv();
```

It captures block mining reward, and manual transactions, but is missing automated contract transactions. I am aware that the script is also missing the genesis block settings, the 5/32 uncle
rewards, and the gas payment to the miner, but what seems puzzling and a big source of inaccuracy at the moment are the missing automated "smart contract" transactions, which I was surprised do not appear in blocks along with ordinary transactions.

Example, for block 1965131 my script reports:

```
1965131,1469670959,M,0x2a65aca4d5fc5b5c859090a6c34d164135398226,5.0
1965131,1469670959,0xd6c9710363cdb12eb585e817f431d44cfa442dde,0xaa1a6e3e6ef20068f7f8d8c835d2d22fd5116444,31.0
1965131,1469670959,0xea674fdde714fd979de3edf0f56aa9716b898ec8,0x3d51978c7b14e486bc7c50c8629b7dc7be6bc405,1.00055988584149
1965131,1469670959,0x447ff4ac930acf585e439de1225fad61389c520e,0xd8e80673419acfbf15bf8eb0239cda90f232051f,32.8088
1965131,1469670959,0x999d1ce359692aebc26cd969a31d47d150128600,0xee48770b4d6fee448b29e2682135147fc059f794,62.219
1965131,1469670959,0x7e12d318239d70a532479b28baa47ec9c4bf83e6,0x556b5712c2a7cc5506fbfa785b52536fb8243765,4000.0
1965131,1469670959,0xf34005bd3186e3ef3ca3452cdd6bb4a7903b1917,0x86290290772671cbd13f1163225e624c67a4675a,10.0
1965131,1469670959,0xea674fdde714fd979de3edf0f56aa9716b898ec8,0x7c43f10e0ff4d33e36437b15b37c30f0d9407af3,0.242703566135995
```

but [Etherchain for block 1965131](https://etherchain.org/block/1965131) includes an additional transaction for 31 ether resulting from activation of a contract.

Over time this kind of omission from the script leads to some wild discrepancies when calculating balances from the data dump, primarily for those accounts that are recipients in smart contract generated transactions.

How can the script be fixed to include the missing smart-contract generated transactions?

Comment: Welcome to the community!  There's no easy way to fix the script and you need an instrumented EVM: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3417/how-to-get-contract-internal-transactions

Comment: @eth  Thanks.  This looked interesting https://blog.ethcore.io/announcing-parity-1-1/

Comment: Good find.  Thanks and as you know feel free to answer your own question and post it to related questions.

Comment: I may if I work out or find a complete solution