# What are Solidity events and how they are related to topics and logs?

Tags: solidity, web3js, events, logs

I know that indexed arguments index the values for those arguments so that filtering will be faster.

But what are topics? And what are they used for?

I know that signature of an event is a topic. And also very index argument is a topic.

And here https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethfilter what do they mean when they say "An array of values which must each appear in the log entries. The order is important, if you want to leave topics out use null, e.g. [null, '0x00...']. You can also pass another array for each topic with options for that topic e.g. [null, ['option1', 'option2']]"

Comment: Signature of an event is a topic? LOG0 has no topic, so the event has no signature?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Topics are indexed parameters to an event.

`topic[0]` always refers to the hash of the hash of the event itself, and can have up to 3 indexed arguments, which will each be reflected in the topics.

EVM uses low-level primitives called logs to map them to high-level Solidity construct called Event. Logs may contain different topics that are indexed arguments.

Consider Event:

```
  event PersonCreated(uint indexed age, uint height);
```

And you fire it the `foobar` function of `MyContract`:

```
  function foobar() {
        emit PersonCreated(26, 176);
  }
```

This will create a low-level EVM log entry with topics

- 0x6be15e8568869b1e100750dd5079151b32637268ec08d199b318b793181b8a7d (Keccak-256 hash of `PersonCreated(uint256,uint256)`)
- 0x36383cc9cfbf1dc87c78c2529ae2fcd4e3fc4e575e154b357ae3a8b2739113cf (Keccak-256 hash of `age`), value 26

You'll notice that height will not be a topic, but it will be included in the data section of the event.

Internally, your Ethereum node (Geth / Parity) will *index* arguments to build on indexable search indexes, so that you can easily do *look ups by value* later. Because creating indexes takes additional disk space, indexed parameters in events have additional gas cost. However, indexed are required to any meaningful look up in scale of events by value later.

Now in the web3 client you want to watch for creation events of all persons that are `age` of 26, you can simply do:

```
var createdEvent = myContract.PersonCreated({age: 26});
createdEvent.watch(function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return;
  }
  console.log("Found ", result);
})
```

Or you could filter all past events in similar fashion.

More information here

- http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html?highlight=topic#modifiers
- http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html?highlight=topic#events
- https://media.consensys.net/technical-introduction-to-events-and-logs-in-ethereum-a074d65dd61e#.7w96id6rs
- https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html

Comment: If the index parameter is a string, bytes or array than the keccak-256 hash of is the topic instead. In the above case age and height shouldn't be hashed. Isn't that right?

Comment: Yes. The  number-like values are pushed through as uint256 is my educated guess.

Comment: How to understand the sentence "the first argument will be used for the data part of the log and the others as topics":
https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html?highlight=Low-Level%20Interface%20to%20Logs

Comment: And if the indexed parameter is an `address` what kind of data we retrieved inside  the logs topics ?

Comment: Address is same as bytes32.