# Get return value of a low level call

Tags: solidity, assembly, calldata, callcode

I'd like to get the return value of a low level call.

```
(bool success, ) = address(0x1234...7890).call{value:0}(callData);
```

[This post discusses a solution](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/59715/11266) that sounds like it should work, but it doesn't have a checkmark and I was unable to get the source working because that last copy command in the toBytes function does not exist.  I tried experimenting in solidity assembly with mload and mstore to make that copy command, but I could not.

```
copy(_addr, btsptr, _len);
```

Does anyone have a complete solution that actually works for this?  Or can anyone help me finish that posted pseudo code from the above-linked post?

Comment: Why not `(bool success, bytes memory data) = ...`, then you can return `data`?

Comment: Is that supposed to work? I haven’t seen that documented anywhere. I will try it today.

Comment: It works only from solc 0.5.x onward, where `call` returns two values - success status and the data returned from the function. And the fact that you have `(bool success, )` in your code implies that your on solc 0.5.x or higher.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!  That seems so obvious, I'm not sure how I missed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from solc 0.5, `call` returns two values:

1. `bool success`, which indicates whether or not the function completed successfully
2. `bytes memory data`, which is the actual data returned from the function

The comma in `(bool success, ) = ...` implies that you are already using solc 0.5 or higher.

So simply change it to `(bool success, bytes memory data) = ...`, and use `data` as desired.