# Can a pruned node do contract.getPastEvents("Transfer", { fromBlock: startBlock})

Tags: web3js, blockchain, contract-invocation, events

Is it possible for a pruned Ethereum node to return data when calling the `getPastEvents()` function on a contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Pruned node removes the historical transaction receipts, which contains data for [events that are stored as receipt logs](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/12951/620).

Any GoEthereum `geth` instance that must serve historical data must run with `--txlookuplimit 0` option (not default) to ensure the node does not prune historical receipts.

Otherwise you may get "Missing Trie Node" or similar error when trying to access historical data.