# How do I check the tx/blocks associated with a smart contract?

Tags: web3.py

I'm trying to get the txs associated with a smart contract to read tx by tx.

I only found one way to do it so far:

(web3.py)

```
first_block = 13123500
block = 13401564

# all the blocks of the contract
while block > first_block:
    print("Block: "+ str(block))

    # JSON from current block
    json_blocks = json.loads(Web3.toJSON(web3.eth.get_block(block)))

    # iterate over transactions of current block
    for x in json_blocks['transactions']:
        try:
            # JSON current tx
            tx_info = json.loads(Web3.toJSON(web3.eth.get_transaction(x)))
            
            # If tx is from our contract
            if tx_info['to'] == keys.CONTRACT_ADDRESS:
                #Do stuff
        except:
            print()

block -= 1
```

But this takes too long...

My question is: Any form to get all the tx from a smart contract without read block by block and later tx by tx?

There are 300.000 blocks to read...

Thanks in advance!

Iván M.M

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: Any form to get all the tx from a smart contract without read block by block and later tx by tx?

No. Unless the smart contract [emits events](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12950/what-are-solidity-events-and-how-they-are-related-to-topics-and-logs/12951#12951) you can capture.