# Is it possible to console(In nodejs) the transaction hash from metamask?

Tags: metamask, nodejs, rinkeby

I am running rinkeby testnet ethereum node in my local. I created one address in my local node using "personal.newAccount()" in geth console.Now I deposited some ethers to my local address through metamask account.Now point is "Is it possible to console(In nodejs) the transaction hash from metamask while depositing the ethers from metamask account to local rinkeby address in nodejs console" Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible since you would have to make metamask execute code that it is not official. What you can do however, it to open metamask and click on the transaction you want to see, then a new window will open on https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/ with your transaction, it's hash will be on the top of the page.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion spirosbax,Is it possible to get that hash( https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/) to node console.

Comment: if you want it being done automatically when you make a transaction you could get the latest transaction's data, from the metamask account you deposited ether, using web3. Take a look at this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8900/how-to-get-transactions-by-account-using-web3-js