# How would one find a list of transactions sent TO an address?

Tags: web3js, transactions, etherscan

I am trying to write a script to audit the changing balance of an ETH address, but I cannot seem to figure out any way to find transactions where ETH has been sent to that address. I couldn't find an appropriate query in the Web3 docs and I couldn't find an appropriate endpoint on the Etherscan API. I would love to find out that I missed it though.

To be more precise, how could you find the transaction with hash `0x8c04e9c806fd7a3273d8a13b54239ab42a5f0b534520e760ccab920bc3d8d59c` (https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8c04e9c806fd7a3273d8a13b54239ab42a5f0b534520e760ccab920bc3d8d59c) if you only had the recipient address `0xe81d6fce840ab873c7bccb6c2ab15e4b6daf92c7` and did not already have the transaction hash?

Note: I chose a plain ETH transfer transaction at random from the Etherscan homepage.

Ideally a solution wouldn't involve querying all transactions in a range and then filtering locally.

EDIT: this is slightly different from ([How to get transactions by account using web3 js?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8900/how-to-get-transactions-by-account-using-web3-js)) because I am OK with using tools outside of web3JS

Comment: Unfortunately geth doesn't provide an api to retrieve transaction history. There are some script that will iterate all blocks but that is slow and misses internal transactions. You have to use a third party api like Etherscan or run your own instnace of a block explorer like blockscout https://github.com/poanetwork/blockscout.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Blockscout is an incredibly helpful tool.

Answer (score 2):

After poking around blockscout per Ismael's suggestion, I found that the transaction I was looking for was available, so blockscout is definitely a viable option if you don't want to resort to iterating over *all* transactions.

However, I found that Etherscan provided the same information and I just completely missed it. For future readers, this `curl` got me all the transactions for the account in the question for the block range 9000000 - 9619126 (there are 163 results) and one of those transactions is the transaction in question:

```
curl http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0xe81d6fce840ab873c7bccb6c2ab15e4b6daf92c7&startblock=9612019&endblock=9619126&sort=asc&apikey=YOUR_ETHERSCAN_API_KEY_HERE
```

Looking at the returned JSON, we can see that there are 113 transactions where the `transaction.to == '0xe81d6fce840ab873c7bccb6c2ab15e4b6daf92c7'`, one of which is transaction `0x8c04e9c806fd7a3273d8a13b54239ab42a5f0b534520e760ccab920bc3d8d59c`