# How do I fetch the entire transaction-history of an address in the fastest way possible?

Tags: transactions, web3.py, json-rpc, history

I just built myself a hardware full node at home. It's running geth and I'm accessing the on-chain data through the JSON RPC API. I'm using web3.py because of convenience.

I want to have a "ledger" basically of all the transactions that I sent or received to a specific address. [This](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/45957/115435) post already detailed how to do this. The only issue is, that my account is kinda old. The script I'm running is able to process aprox 1.000 blocks within 3 minutes. If we extrapolate a little bit here, 1.000.000 blocks would roughly take 2 days. 10.000.000 blocks would roughly take 20 days. Blockheight 6.000.000 as an example is dated Jul-20-2018. So even if my script ran 20 days non-stop, I still wouldn't have found all the transactions associated with the account. Is there anything I can do to speed this up? I'm kinda dumbfounded because I thought there was a more efficient way to do this.

Edit1: I should mention that I obviously know about etherscan etc., but the idea of spinning up my own node was to have my own server to serve requests at any point. I want to play around locally, without any 3rd party provider. I hope this works somehow...

Just for completion, here's the function I'm calling:

```py
def getAllTransactionsOfAddress(address):
    transactionCount = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(address,currentBlock)
    addressBalance = w3.eth.getBalance(address,currentBlock)
    i = currentBlock
    while i >= 0 and (transactionCount > 0 or addressBalance > 0):
        try:
            block = w3.eth.get_block(i, True)
            if block and block.transactions:
                for transaction in block.transactions:
                    if address == transaction['from']:
                        if transaction['from'] != transaction.to:
                            addressBalance = addressBalance + transaction.value
                        print(transaction.blockHash,transaction.hash,transaction['from'],transaction.to)
                        transactionCount -= transactionCount
                    if address == transaction.to:
                        if transaction['from'] != transaction.to:
                            addressBalance = addressBalance - transaction.value
                        print(transaction.blockHash,transaction.hash,transaction['from'],transaction.to)
        except:
            print("Error in block"+i)
        i-=1
        if i % 1000 == 0:
            print(str(i) + " " + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
```

Thanks and Cheers!

Comment: If you want the fastest way and don't care about the cost. I would recommend Google BigQuery. Likely instant result, much faster than looking up your own node.

Comment: Thank you for your answer =) I would make a note of this answer as a last resort if there is no other way. Because then it would feel like setting up my own node was kind of pointless. Maybe one day I'll become a validator myself, but until then I was going to play around with the web3.py library, assuming I'd be able to write programs/scripts using the node as my data source. But if it's too slow to serve those needs, I'd be a bit disappointed.