# UTXO Output greater than Input

Tags: transactions, accounts, balances, internal-transactions

I reviewed the transactions from a recent ICO.  The account below provided the largest investment.  If you check the account,  there is a far greater Out value than In.   I was under the impression that IN and OUT had to be equal.  How is this possible?

https://etherscan.io/txs?a=0xa65e9fec4f892ef6e9fe3888ed9b0eb6aab1f0fd

Just curious

Thanks

Comment: Hi there. Just as an aside: "UTXO" is a Bitcoin concept - it doesn't translate to Ethereum.

Answer (score 1):

The accounting has to work, yes, in that what remains in the account has to balance what's come in and gone out.

What you're missing are the internal transactions, made as a result of contract execution.

There are two large [internal transactions](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa65e9fec4f892ef6e9fe3888ed9b0eb6aab1f0fd#internaltx) made *to* that address:

- 18,833 ETH from `0xb565F9f09bcC7BBA5d2CbE6ba8f57aDAE15C6ab0`
- 10,487 ETH from `0x1644033f911e777Ad69C0fbe60A44594011B56fd`

Both of these are wallet contracts [[1](https://etherscan.io/address/0xb565f9f09bcc7bba5d2cbe6ba8f57adae15c6ab0#code), [2]](https://etherscan.io/address/0x1644033f911e777ad69c0fbe60a44594011b56fd#code).

These balance nicely with the two big payments *from* the address:

- [18,832](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x86dc0133196aefe98503149610dfc72faeedfe9e0066d0d660f0cc49a4dc8930) ETH <- iEx.ec crowdsale
- [10,486](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x957471523658c6c0e2cbfc11e3f3727253b62161e105539c8d2610bfc1be8093) ETH <- Matchpool crowdsale

Comment: @sparcusa: One reference for "internal transactions" https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3417/how-to-get-contract-internal-transactions