# does the transaction trie include the contract internal transactions?

Tags: transactions

Does the transaction trie include the contract internal transactions besides the transactions collected from the network? if not, how the contract internal transactions are handled in the EVM and being stored in the block?

Answer (score 1):

> Does the transaction trie include the contract internal transactions besides the transactions collected from the network?

No. Internal transactions - also known as "messages" - are not "real" transactions, and are not stored in the state data.

> If not, how the contract internal transactions are handled in the EVM and being stored in the block?

They're not stored in the blocks/state data. If you want to get the details of an internal transaction, you'll either have to use a third-party service, such as Etherscan, or run an instrumented node yourself.

(See: [How to get contract internal transactions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3417/how-to-get-contract-internal-transactions). <- This may well be a duplicate.)