# How to get type of a contract internal transaction?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, etherscan, nodejs

I'd like to get type(create, call, ...) of a contract internal transaction, like [this page of etherscan.][1]
However, I couldn't find it any responses and documents of web3js.

I'm getting a contract internal transaction by following procedure.

1. Use eth.getTransactionReceipt() about a transaction.
2. See a contractAddress property in the response of step 1.
3. If the contractAddress property has an address, the transaction is a contract internal transaction.

Is this right ?

However, if the procedure is right, the response of step 1 does not have type of a contract internal transaction. Also a response of eth.getTransaction() about same txHash as step 1 does not have type of contract internal transaction.

I saw [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3417/how-to-get-contract-internal-transactions).
However I couldn't uncderstand clearly.
Is it impossible getting type of contract internal transaction?

My environmet is here.

geth:1.9.11-stable
web3js:2.0.0-alpha.1

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3417/how-to-get-contract-internal-transactions?rq=1 answers your question

Comment: There is no API for it. You need to trace the transaction in an Ethereum Virtual Machine yourself and extract the information that way.

Comment: Ok. I see.
Thanks!